# Bootstrap carousel will not work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Boostrap Carousel and have set the data-interval to 5000 (also tried 10000 milliseconds). Tried to add the JavaScript as well, without any luck.

This is my code:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="{% static "pic-1" %}" alt="x">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="{% static "pic-2.png" %}" alt="x">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried adding this at the end of the HTML:

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `carousel` in jQuery ready funciton:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 5000
    });

  });
```

Comment: Do you have `jquery` in your html?

Comment: Yes, I have added it in the header.

Comment: make sure you import `jquery` before your script tag or any other javascript file. that's all I can think of. Other than that, probably check if you have the right code for bootstrap carousel.